# ClassNotFound Exception while trying to use Google OAuth API on Eclipse & Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, google-oauth

After adding Google OAuth2 API v. 2 (listed as "preferred") from Google API loader (right click on Project -> Google -> Add Google APIs...) in Eclipse, my servlet fails with following traceback:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at com.some.my.backend.MyServlet.myMethod(MyServlet.java:268)
    and so on.
```

Everything compiles OK and "Run on Server" otherwise works normally. I assume something is broken with the way Eclipse deploys the web app to Tomcat.

I also tried to download the Google client zip by hand, unpacked it and added all the jars to the Java Build Path from Project Properties. The result was the same.

I am trying to compile the Checker class [of this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html).

Isn't adding Google APIs supposed to be as simple as described above? What am I doing wrong?